# No Type was found that matches Controller non-MVC ASP.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Currently I am creating a web application using a non-mvc web API in .NET. We are also using AngularJS to call the API with.

Here is the Router:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class signOnController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetSingleSignOn()
    {
        singleSignOn sign = new singleSignOn();
        var check = sign.executeStoredProcedure();

        if (check == 0)
        {
            return Ok("http://localhost:64325/EmployeeIndex.html#/form/begin");
        }
        else if (check == 1)
        {
            return Ok("http://localhost:64325/ManagerIndex.html#/form/begin");
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the angularJS:

```
formApp.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var result;

    this.GetApiCall = function (controllerName, methodName) {
     result = $http.get('api/' + controllerName + '/' + methodName).success(function (data, status) {
        result = data;
    }).error(function () {
        alert("API Get call error");
    });
    return result;
};
```

I keep getting this error when I try to run it:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51463/api/signOnController/GetSingleSignOn'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No type was found that matches the controller named 'signOnController'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be mentioning `Controller` inside route name. It should be

http://localhost:51463/api/signOn/GetSingleSignOn

---

Though you can use Route Attribute to define Routing to make route more verbose.

```
[Route("SingleSignOn")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSingleSignOn() {
    ....
}
```

Then URL will be like `http://localhost:51463/api/signOn/SingleSignOn`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved that problem, now I am having a back-end code issue but nothing a little more debugging won't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the route should be `http://localhost:51463/api/signOn/GetSingleSignOn`.  controller name is just for identifying it is a controller.in routes you must use this without the word `Controller`. but when creating a controller make sure you include the word

secondly, i think what you exactly want to achieve is a route like in MVC. change your router to include `action`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

the default asp webapi routes are for pure REST API implementation which is not suitable for most cases.

Comment: Was talking with a Senior software architect about how we would implement this. It's for a senior project, he said that a MVC architecture for our web application would be unnecessary and that all we would need is a Web API.

Comment: well thats true, but default routing is not suitable for most cases , so you may need to change that. it is for routes like for example ``names/1`` if it is a get request then get resources, if it is a post then add resource, if it is a delete request then delete data etc. for normal routing change the routing strategy to include action. that is recommended

Comment: Thanks, yeah we will see. We have about four or five more main pieces of functionality to build out in our API so we will see how it goes without using MVC.